# How to use the TypeScript compiler's type inferencing engine?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have some JSON data that looks like:

```
const x = {
    a: "apples",
    b: [1, 2, 3],
}
```

When I hover over this value in VSCode, the TypeScript compiler has inferred the type of this object to be:

```
const x: {
    a: string;
    b: number[];
}
```

My question is, where in the TypeScript compiler is this happening and how can I call a function that will interpret some JSON into this inferred schema? I'm hunting around the [TypeScript compiler source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src) and I'm completely lost.